# SwiftUI ForEach statement iterate the list twice

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've got ForEach loop inside a picker widget, that suppose to iterate a list of items (`handler.items`).

However, in reality, I get that the tags where not properly set and `$arg = $0` instead of `$arg = $0.components(separatedBy: " ")[0]`

after debugging the problem, it seems that although i see the right number of items according to the list size ... the ForEach iterate all the items twice, thus causing duplicated tags where they suppose to be unique.

here's the code, any idea how come the iteration repeat itself ?

```
VStack {
    Picker("items", selection: $arg) {
        ForEach(handler.items , id: \.self, content: {
            Text($0).tag($0.components(separatedBy: " ")[0])
        })
    }
}
```

and here's how handler.items are defined. it's actually a separated object that is visible from the view, and can be changed from swift native methods.

```
class myHandler: ObservableObject {
  @Published var items = [String]()
}
```

when setting a breakpoint in the `ForEach` statement, i could print this object

```
(lldb) p handler.items
([String]) $R1 = 2 values {
  [0] = "aaa bbb cc 1.1.1.1"
  [1] = "ddd eee ff 2.2.2.2"
}
```

When i put breakpoint inside the ForEach body, I could see that the breakpoint caught there 4 times, and printing the iterator value i Got this printouts:

```
aaa bbb cc 1.1.1.1
ddd eee ff 2.2.2.2
aaa bbb cc 1.1.1.1
ddd eee ff 2.2.2.2
```

EDIT : here's a minimal reproducible example. notice the circled text that clearly shows that the arg didn't get the tag expression but the whole item :
[image]

Comment: If you have the right number of items in the list how can you then have twice as many tags? Did you try to use the item itself ($0) as the tag?

Comment: please provide what handler.items is. otherwise it's hard to say what's happening

Comment: @cole, I've added the data you requested. thanks for trying to help here.

Comment: @Zohar81 but what does your ObservableObject published variable items contain? As far as I can see it doesn't hold any values.

Comment: @cole, my published variable contains exactly the 2 values (I've added the lldb command to support this).

Comment: @Zohar81 so these two strings? "aaa bbb cc 1.1.1.1" and "ddd eee ff 2.2.2.2"

Comment: yes, it's a list of 2 strings as you mentioned. and I expected to get a unique tags "aaa" and "ddd" but since it caught on the breakpoint 4 times inside the same iteration, I assume that the tags are not unique, and $args get the default value which is the entire string.

Comment: @Zohar81 I'm still not following the question. What's the purpose of the tag and how are you setting the string? I'm not sure what the outcome is suppose to look like. A picker with strings or numbers?

Comment: Just because the breakpoint is hit four times doesn’t mean that four tags exists, everything was probably replaced the second time so you have two items with a separate unique tag.

Comment: I do not get what you show with your EDIT picture. On macos only app (Monterey), I get `Text(arg)`  showing 
"aaa" or "ddd". This is with and without any `pickerStyle` as you show in your picture.

Comment: @workingdog, notice that I got this result in macOS bigSur.. maybe that's the problem and it fixed in Monterey.

Comment: yep, I reckon so.

Comment: May be the SwiftUI implementation needs to go twice the loop : once to compute offscreen the size of each Text to compute the size of each element to be displayed and the second time to display the do onscreen display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have `.pickerStyle(.wheel)` to make it work on ios devices. Here is the code I used for testing:

(on macos 12.3-beta, using xcode 13.3-beta, targets ios 15 and macCatalyst 12)

```
class MyHandler: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [String] = ["aaa bbb cc 1.1.1.1", "ddd eee ff 2.2.2.2"]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var handler = MyHandler()
    @State var arg = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(arg) // <-- to display arg
            Picker("items", selection: $arg) {
                ForEach(handler.items , id: \.self) { str in
                    let _ = print(str.components(separatedBy: " ")[0]) // <-- to print tag values
                    Text(str).tag(str.components(separatedBy: " ")[0])
                }
            }.pickerStyle(.wheel)  // <--- here
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT-1:
Note, on macos (Monterey) only app,  `pickerStyle` with `radioGroup`, `segmented` and `inline`, will work (i.e, no repeat of tags),
however,  `menu`, and `automatic` do not.

On ios/mac Catalyst, `wheel`, `inline`, `segmented` and `automatic` work, but `menu` does not.

Comment: very surprised that my code does not work. Can whoever downvoted my answer explain what is not working in my code or if it does not address the question "....any idea how come the iteration repeat itself ?". 
Does the ForEach iterate all the items twice with my code?

Comment: I didn’t downvote but what has picker style got to do with the question and what has iOS got to do with the question?

Comment: the question as I see it, 
"... the ForEach iterate all the items twice, thus causing duplicated tags where they suppose to be unique". My answer 
"...the ForEach does not iterate all the items twice with my code".  Without the `pickerStyle` the ForEach does iterate all the items twice.
Yes I assumed, maybe wrongly, that it was to do with ios. I did not check for macos only app. Is this the reason for the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvoted either, and it actually helped me debug my problem with minimal reproducible example... But when i opened a new macOS application (not iOS), it showed my problem loud and clear

Comment: updated my answer with more info.

Comment: @workingdog, do you know if the duplicated tags appear when running on BigSur 11.6 ?

Comment: ha, I just posted a comment to your question, with Monterey. Unfortunately I do not have Big Sur anymore. This could well be the main issue here.

Comment: @workingdog The picker style has nothing to do with why he’s getting duplicates.  An ObservableObject is overkill for something we know, the strings. Why make more work for yourself, end duplications period.

Answer (score -2):

Well I suggest moving the strings to a custom `enumeration` instead of your `ObservableObject`. Setting the tag doesn't really need to be done then. And no duplicate entries

Here’s an example from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/picker)

```swift
enum Items: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case a = "aaa bbb cc 1.1.1.1"
    case b = "ddd eee ff 2.2.2.2"
    var id: Self { self }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var selection = Items.a

    var body: some View {
        
        Picker("Items", selection: $selection) {
            ForEach(Items.allCases) { item in
                Text(item.rawValue)
            }
        }

    }
}
```